# Flutter web image picker

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Я использую 'package:image_picker_web/image_picker_web.dart'; На данный момент я могу выбрать картинку и отобразить ее в виджете, но при сохранении в storage картинка не сохраняется. Картинка в формате  Uint8List. Можно ли конвертировать Uint8List в File? 
код:

```
 Uint8List _image1;
      Future getImg() async {
        Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);

        if (tempImg != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image1 = tempImg;
          });
        }
      }
```

код сохранения в storage

```
Future uploadImg() async {
final file = File.fromRawPath(_image1);
StorageReference productImg =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('ProductImg');
var timekey = DateTime.now();
StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
    productImg.child(timekey.toString() + 'jpg').putFile(file);
var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
url = imageUrl.toString();
print('Image Url' + url);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Решить вашу проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Хранить в базе данных `Uint8List` и использовать его с помощью `Image.memory(_image1);`. Ещё можно конвертировать `Uint8List` в `BASE64` для хранения в базе данных: `base64.encode(_image1);`
2. Использовать библиотеку [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image)

Пример:

```
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getImg(),
      builder: (BuildContext snapshot, AsyncSnapshot<File> img) =>
          Image.file(img.data),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Future<File> getImg() async {
  Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);
  IMG.Image img = IMG.decodeImage(tempImg);
  File imgFile = File('img.jpg')..writeAsBytes(IMG.encodeJpg(img));
  return imgFile;
}
...
```

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsBytesSync.html

Comment: Как я понимаю ваш первый вариант это как у меня? код в моем примере на сохранение в firebase storage не работает. Если я правильно понял это из за `Uint8List`

Comment: @AndreyKhan Нет **первый вариант** именно для базы данных (Firebase Cloud Firestore или Firebase Realtime Database), хранения в виде объекта (строки). Для Firebase Storage подойдет **второй вариант**, так как в нем можно хранить файлы. _Если вам нужен пример напишите, я добавлю его в ответ._

Comment: ок понял. По поводу 2 варианта, библиотеку нужно использовать вместе с Future getImg()? или отдельно? Именно здесь не могу разобраться.

Comment: @AndreyKhan да, с `getImg()` получаете `Uint8List`, а дальше по примеру. Также обратите внимание на `writeAsBytesSync` и ссылки ниже, выберите метод подходящий вам! Скорее всего это будет `writeAsBytes`, так как вам нужно его использовать в `putFile()`.

Comment: _image1 обозначил как `File _image1`          
`void getImg() async {
    Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);
    IMG.Image img = IMG.decodeWebP(tempImg);
    var imgFile = File('img.jpg')..writeAsBytes(IMG.encodeJpg(img));

    if (imgFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        // debugPrint(tempImg.toString());
        _image1 = imgFile;
      });
    }
  }`

Comment: _image1 не отображается в виджете, `return Image.file(_image1);`

Comment: Как правильней будет, хранить как файл в storage или как string в формате base 64?

Comment: @AndreyKhan обновил код, как работает не проверял (возможно будет ругаться на `File('img.jpg')`, так как там не указан путь). По поводу как хранить, все зависит от задач: Если просто хранение, то лучше base64. Если предполагаться трансформация с помощью бекенда, то лучше в виде файла.

Comment: Долгими путями нашел выход, теперь картинка отправляется в storage. но только как файл html. Теперь не могу ее отобразить в виджете)

Comment: @AndreyKhan должно помочь) https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html